# How to refresh the ListView out of the CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I've got a ListView in my Activity, which is set in the `onCreate` by

```
    MyCursorAdapter adapter = new TaskConditsCursorAdapter(this, conditsCursor, taskID, isNewTask);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then I do some work in the `MyCursorAdapter`. Amongst others I have a rowspecific AlertDialog:

```
...
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            changeTaskConditBoolValue(taskId, conditId, chosenBoolValue2);
            // refresh?
        }
    });
```

After the `changeTaskConditBoolValue` I want to reload my List, since this method changed something in the database, but the List didn't update. `requery()` results in the list being empty. 
How can I come "one level above" to work with the `adapter` again and what should I do to it then?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

In the `MyCursorAdapter` in the method called by the `onClick` - in my case it is `changeTaskConditBoolValue(...)` I have to call:

```
this.changeCursor(db.fetchAllTasks(myParameters));
```

This gets a new cursor by my Database-Class and replaces its own old one with the new one.

Found no other way to change the cursor from inside the CursorAdapter.

Comment: Are you calling this.changeCursor(db.fetchAllTasks(myParameters)); on the UI Thread? I am having difficutlry on doing this on a separate thread. Since I could not have my loader to reload data. I could if I get the cursor with new data but I have to call this on the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

Just call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Documentation: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: Beat me to it... I guess if you're inside your own Adapter classes code though, you'd just use notifyDataSetChanged() or this.notifyDataSetChanged() though.

Comment: Thnak you, but unfortunatly none of that worked correctly. 
They just have no effect... Anything I should pay attention to regarding it?
I really have to show the correct data in the ListView

Comment: As I understand it, I should have to use requery() because I changed something in the database and the cursor holds the outdated data. But everytime I requery, the list is completely empty - not even the ImageViews are displyed...

Comment: having the same issue as you, any possibility you found the solution?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is not working for me either. It seems there is no longer need to call this if you are using Cursors.

Answer (score 1):

calling requery() of adapter is the only solution.

But the method requery() is deprecated. So we can use LoaderManager and Loader.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me, im not sure its the best way.

```
c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM mytable", null); //same line of the initial initialization
adapter.swapCursor(c);
```

I refresh the only cursor, I dont know what to do with a new one.